# Have multiple commands when button is pressed

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter, command

I want to run multiple functions when I click a button. For example I want my button to look like

```
self.testButton = Button(self, text = "test", 
                         command = func1(), command = func2())
```

when I execute this statement I get an error because I cannot allocate something to an argument twice. How can I make command execute multiple functions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could create a generic function for combining functions, it might look something like this:

```
def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func
```

Then you could create your button like this:

```
self.testButton = Button(self, text = "test", 
                         command = combine_funcs(func1, func2))
```

Comment: How to do this if this `combine_funcs` is method in a class? If I write `def combine_funcs(self, *funcs):` I get an error `TypeError: my_first_func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 60):

You can simply use lambda like this:

```
self.testButton = Button(self, text=" test", command=lambda:[funct1(),funct2()])
```

Answer (score 18):

```
def func1(evt=None):
    do_something1()
    do_something2()
    ...

self.testButton = Button(self, text = "test", 
                         command = func1)
```

maybe?

I guess maybe you could do something like

```
self.testButton = Button(self, text = "test", 
                         command = lambda x:func1() & func2())
```

but that is really gross ...

Comment: Defining a function to do what you want is probably the best solution. Putting some of the logic within the button itself strikes me as icky, and a potential maintenance problem later.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the lambda for this:

```
self.testButton = Button(self, text = "test", lambda: [f() for f in [func1, funct2]])
```

Answer (score 5):

`Button(self, text="text", command=func_1()and func_2)`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to run multiple functions by use lambda.

here an example:

```
button1 = Button(window,text="Run", command = lambda:[fun1(),fun2(),fun3()])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found also this, which works for me. In a situation like...

```
b1 = Button(master, text='FirstC', command=firstCommand)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=15)

b2 = Button(master, text='SecondC', command=secondCommand)
b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

master.mainloop()
```

... you can do...

```
b1 = Button(master, command=firstCommand)
b1 = Button(master, text='SecondC', command=secondCommand)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=15)

master.mainloop()
```

What I did was just renaming the second variable `b2` the same as the first `b1` and deleting, in the solution, the first button text (so only the second is visible and will act as a single one).

I also tried the function solution but for an obscure reason it don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

this is a short example : while pressing the next button it will execute 2 functions in 1 command option

```
    from tkinter import *
    window=Tk()
    v=StringVar()
    def create_window():
           next_window=Tk()
           next_window.mainloop()

    def To_the_nextwindow():
        v.set("next window")
        create_window()
   label=Label(window,textvariable=v)
   NextButton=Button(window,text="Next",command=To_the_nextwindow)

   label.pack()
   NextButton.pack()
   window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out, I have tried this method as,I was facing the same problem. This worked for me.

```
def all():
    func1():
        opeartion
    funct2():
        opeartion
    for i in range(1):
        func1()
        func2()

self.testButton = Button(self, text = "test", command = all)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for different solution. One button doing two functions on two different clicks. Example START button - after click changes text to STOP and starts function. After second click stop function and changes text to START again.
Tried this and it works. I do not know if it is ok or elegant or does not break any python rules (I am a lousy programmer :-) but it works.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def start_proc():
    print('Start')
    myButton.configure(text='STOP',command=stop_proc)

def stop_proc():
    print('stop')
    myButton.configure(text='START',command=start_proc)

myButton=Button(root,text='START' ,command=start_proc)
myButton.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for contributing. This is surely useful, but it answers a different question, not the OP's. If you feel like sharing your knowledge, consider posting your own question; you are then free to post an answer to your own question, too. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32570349)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by simply adding your second function at the end of the first function, but only passing the first function as a command. This will trigger both functions but following a sequence.
I like this approach as it allows for a greater flexibility since you can add custom logic to be followed before the second function is called. 
*PS: In your code you should avoid adding ( ) when binding your function with  the* **command** arg as you did.

```
def func1():
    pass
    #code to execute before func2() is called

    def func2():
        pass
        #code of func2()

    pass
    #code after func2() is executed
```