# Tkinter - Same event for multiple buttons

Tags: events, tkinter

Using Tkinter, I have many buttons. I would like the same callback function to be triggered every time any of the buttons pressed. How can I find out which button was pressed ?

```
def call(p1):
    # Which Button was pressed?
    pass

for i in range (50):
    B1 = Button(master, text = '...', width = 2)
    B1.grid(row = i*20, column = 60)               
    B1.bind('<Button-1>',call)

    B2 = Button(master, text = '...', width = 2)
    B2.grid(row = i*20, column = 60)               
    B2.bind('<Button-1>',call)
```

Answer (score 11):

Using a list to reference the dynamically created buttons and lambda to store a reference to the index of the button object. You can determine which button was clicked. In the below examples I use `.cget("text")` on the button object to demonstrate accessing the button widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(200, 200)

btn_list = [] # List to hold the button objects

def onClick(idx):
    print(idx) # Print the index value
    print(btn_list[idx].cget("text")) #Print the text for the selected button

for i in range(10):
    # Lambda command to hold reference to the index matched with range value
    b = tk.Button(root, text = 'Button #%s' % i, command = lambda idx = i: onClick(idx))
    b.grid(row = i, column = 0)

    btn_list.append(b) # Append the button to a list

root.mainloop()
```

---

Alternatively you can use bind and then access the widget from the event object generated.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(200, 200)

def onClick(event):
    btn = event.widget # event.widget is the widget that called the event
    print(btn.cget("text")) #Print the text for the selected button

for i in range(10):
    b = tk.Button(root, text = 'Button #%s' % i)
    b.grid(row = i, column = 0)
    # Bind to left click which generates an event object
    b.bind("<Button-1>", onClick)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. @Steven Summers' first example seems most clear to me, but I think doing it without the list is even clearer.
2. The way I understood the question, you not only want to know which button was clicked but you *also* want each button to call one other, undescribed function (`universal` in my example below). In that case, you can use the very handy
   `combine_funcs` (see: [Have multiple commands when button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865009/have-multiple-commands-when-button-is-pressed-in-tkinter-with-python-2-7)) to call two functions from one widget.

Here is my code. Instead of a list, I simply have a string that is changed and printed with each click.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(200, 200)

buttonVal = ''                             

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func

def universal():
    print 'Universal function is called'    

def button_check(buttonName):
    buttonVal = buttonName
    print buttonVal   # Or whatever you want to do with the button info

for i in range(10):
    B1 = tk.Button(root, text = 'Button #%s' % i, command = combine_funcs(universal, lambda buttonName = 'Button #%s' % i:button_check(buttonName)))
    B1.grid(row = i, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lambda`:

```
B1 = Button(master, text = '...', width = 2, command = lambda: call('B1') )
```

And so on...

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the simplest solution, but it is the only one I could come up with.

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()

L = []

def call(p1):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if str(L[i]) == str(p1.widget):
            print 'Button' + str(i)
            break  

for i in range (50):
    exec("Button" + str(i) + " = Button(master, text = '...', width = 2)")
    exec("Button" + str(i) + ".grid(row = i*20, column = 60)")               
    exec("Button" + str(i) + ".bind('<Button-1>',call)")

    s = 'L.append(str(Button' + str(i) + '))'
    exec(s)
```

Comment: Why are you using `exec`? It makes no sense.