# Python, tkinter: Bind all buttons to <Return>, so their callback will be triggered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to bind all instances of `ttk.Button` in my app in a single bind to `'<Return>'` event, so when Enter button is pressed, `ttk.Button` callback will be triggered.

In addition, some buttons may have a `lambda` callback, so is there a generalised way to do that?

I know this can be done by explicitly binding every button, but can it be done with `bind_class`, perhaps? Or subclassing a ttk.Button?

Clarification:
I don't want the **same** callback be triggered when any of the buttons are pressed with  button.
I want buttons **own** callback triggered, when this particular button is in focus and  button is pressed on keyboard.
And this is not a default behavior of a `ttk.Button` widget.

I am using Python 3.

Comment: so that they get invoked? (Their `command` gets called)  That should happen by default.  Or do you mean you want to call a single callback when *any* button is selected when the user hits `<Return>` in which case yes you would use `bind_class`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I would like to make single bind statement. In the end, when some particular button is in focus and Return is pressed, I would like to get this specific focused Button to be invoked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter - Same event for multiple buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470943/tkinter-same-event-for-multiple-buttons)

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: No, the subject is different. I 've added clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually invoke a button using their `.invoke()` method, since you are making a binding you will have access to the specific widget in question with `e.widget` and invoke that specific button:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="button1",
                    command = lambda:print("hit button1"))
button1.grid()
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="button2",
                    command = lambda:print("hit button2"))
button2.grid()

def wrapper(e):
    print("<Return> was pressed on a button!")
    e.widget.invoke()
root.bind_class("Button","<Return>",wrapper)
root.mainloop()
```

Now if you press `<Return>` while one of the buttons have focus `wrapper` will be called and then `invoke()` the specific button that was in focus.

Comment: Just in case somebody else would face the same problem, for binding `ttk.Button` instances `root.bind_class("TButton","<Return>",wrapper)` should be used

Comment: I didn't actually know that, Thanks for the info @MikhailT.