# TKINTER QUIZ GAME

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in programming and in Python. I am trying to build a quiz game with tkinter in which I call a csv file that has 6 columns, (QUESTION, ANSWERA, ANSWERB, ANSWERC, ANSWERD, CORRECTANSWER) in a python file. I have an entry box(for the questions) and 4 buttons(for the answers).

My question: How do I interate through the list created for the csv file through the command in the buttons?

When I click on the button, with the right or wrong answer, I want it to change the text at the buttons and take the values from the next row in the list.

My code:

```
from tkinter import*
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
root = Tk()
root.title("ΜΑΘΕ ΠΑΙΖΟΝΤΑΣ")
root.geometry('1352x652+0+0')
root.configure(background = 'blue')

#=================CONNECT TO DATABASE csv=========================
import csv
import unicodedata

with open('questiondb.csv',newline='',encoding="utf8")as csvfile:
    csvreader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
    rows=list(csvreader)
    for i in range(1,3):
        print(rows[i])
#=================functions=============
def correct_answer_funcA():
    if answerA==correctanswer:
        print ("right!!!")
    else:
        print("wrong!!")
def correct_answer_funcB():
    if answerB==correctanswer:
        print ("right!!!")
    else:
        print("wrong!!")
def correct_answer_funcC():
    if answerC==correctanswer:
        print ("right!!!")
    else:
        print("wrong!!")
def correct_answer_funcD():
    if answerD==correctanswer:
        print ("right!!!")
    else:
        print("wrong!!")

#===============TEXT,LABELS,BUTTON=======================
i=1
questions=rows[i][1]
answerA=rows[i][2]
answerB=rows[i][3]
answerC=rows[i][4]
answerD=rows[i][5]
correctanswer=rows[i][6]


txtQuestion = Entry(ABC1c, font=('arial', 18,'bold'),bg='red', fg='white', bd=1, width=44,justify=CENTER)
txtQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=4)
txtQuestion.insert(INSERT,questions)

lblQuestA = Label(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),text="A: ",bg='black', fg='white', bd=1, justify=CENTER)
lblQuestA.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=4, sticky=W)
txtQuestion1 = Button(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),bg='blue', fg='white', bd=1, width=17, height=2,justify=CENTER, text=answerA, command=correct_answer_funcA)
txtQuestion1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=4)

lblQuestB = Label(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),text="B: ",bg='black', fg='white', bd=1,justify=LEFT)
lblQuestB.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=4, sticky=W)
txtQuestion2 = Button(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),bg='blue', fg='white', bd=1, width=17, height=2,justify=CENTER, text = answerB, command=correct_answer_funcB)
txtQuestion2.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=4)

lblQuestC = Label(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),text="C: ",bg='black', fg='white', bd=1, justify=CENTER)
lblQuestC.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=4, sticky=W)
txtQuestion3 = Button(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),bg='blue', fg='white', bd=1, width=17, height=2,justify=CENTER, text = answerC, command=correct_answer_funcC)
txtQuestion3.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=4)

lblQuestD = Label(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),text="B: ",bg='black', fg='white', bd=1,justify=LEFT)
lblQuestD.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=4, sticky=W)
txtQuestion4 = Button(ABC1c, font=('arial', 14,'bold'),bg='blue', fg='white', bd=1, width=17, height=2,justify=CENTER, text = answerD, command=correct_answer_funcD)
txtQuestion4.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)
```

Comment: ***how to interate in the list***: Unfortunately you don't show how you read the values into the`list`!

Comment: hello !!
from tkinter import*
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
root = Tk()
root.title("ΜΑΘΕ ΠΑΙΖΟΝΤΑΣ")
root.geometry('1352x652+0+0')
root.configure(background = 'blue')

#==============CONNECT TO DATABASE csv==================================
import csv

import unicodedata

with open('questiondb.csv',newline='',encoding="utf8")as csvfile:
    csvreader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
    rows=list(csvreader)
    for i in range(1,3):
        print(rows[i])

Comment: Thank you. I edited the code to show how i read the values

Comment: Change to `.bind("<Button-1>", onClick)` accordingly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35473579/7414759) for **all** `Button` so you have to deal with only **one** callback.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT

Comment: thank you stovfl for your help. The problem i face is when i call the function  onClick or any function when i click the buttons i cannot clear the button and call the new records. 
i use for loop to call the next record but i have the following error 
    **if answerA==correctanswer:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'answerA' referenced before assignment**