# Getting a not Definded error when the program tries to close the window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Experimenting with Tkinter and Gui creating and cant seem to run two commands off of one button press.

I've already tried moving the second definition out of the first definition to the same error as before. The problem is that it is a separate window to my main window and so is under a different definition meaning. When I've tried the previous threads answers it isn't working for me.

```
def cheese():
    fll = Tk()

    #The two commands linked together
    def fildes():
        filling2()
        fll.destroy

    fll.title=("Test")

    ll = Label(fll, text ="Would you like to choose another topping?").pack()
    #The button under this runs fildes()
    bb = Button(fll, text ="Yep", command = fildes).pack()
    bbb = Button(fll, text ="No", command = fll.destroy).pack()
```

It should create a window and when the yes button is pressed open a new window while closing the current window.

It opens the new window but fails too delete the current window due to fll not being defined

```
    def fildes():
        filling2()
        fll.destroy()
```

this does not work either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have multiple commands when button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865009/have-multiple-commands-when-button-is-pressed)

Comment: I had a look at that that's why I wrote this none of those answers seem to work for me? I think its because its inside a definition which It needs to be as it comes from another button to this one.

Comment: in above code, you are not _calling_ `destroy` inside `fildes`.

Comment: Okay so is there anyway for me to call destroy inside fildes?

Comment: Should be `fll.destroy()`, not `fll.destroy` inside  `fildes`.

Comment: Thanks ill try that now. It doesn't work for some reason the tab stays open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

Always **try to pass the arguments to your functions**. If I'm seeing this right, Tkinter only calls the standalone  `filedes()` function, without any knowledge about local variables in *cheese*.

**Pass the window** you want destroyed **to *filedes*** like this:

```
def fildes(old:Tk):
    old.destroy()
    filling2()
```

Then **add *fll* as parameter** to the *command* of your button. [(Can be done like this.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

```
bb = Button(fll, text ="Yep", command = lambda: fildes(fll))
```

*PS*:

When I tried to run your code I had to call `.pack()` like this or else it wouldn't work:

```
sample = Button()
sample.pack()
```

Comment: PPS:
The Title of this question doesn't seem to fit the problem, since you've already solved the problem of passing several arguments via a wrapper function. I would recommend you to change it.

Comment: will do. I run the     .pack() later in the code so it isn't here

Comment: also how would I run the filling2() off of this?

Comment: just put filling2() where i put cheese() in filedes. 
I edited it

Comment: Yep thanks for that