# How can I make a sound when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, audio

Now I am going to design a little GUI game like find a pair. And I want to add the sound effect when I click every buttons on it. But I don't know how to add these sound. As the previous answer
[How can I play a sound when a tkinter button is pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795859/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-a-tkinter-button-is-pushed)
said, I need to defined the button as this way:

```
Button(root, text="Play music", command=play_music).pack()
```

The button has another feature.

```
Button(game_window,image=blank_image,command=cell_0).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

So how `'command=play_music'` should be placed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have multiple commands when button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865009/have-multiple-commands-when-button-is-pressed)

Comment: It really help, thx.

Answer (score 0):

make a change like this:

```
Button(game_window,image=blank_image,command=lambda:[cell_0(),play()]).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Then it works.

Comment: lambda expressions should only used if really needed, while its hard to debug. For the same reason I wouldnt recommand to use multiple functions in a lambda expression. It could give you a hard time to find out what happens here, while it dosent throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to alter your functions with a common functionality. For this [decorators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsAPt_9Bf3U) are really good. A decorator allows you to add functionality to existing functions. An exampel can be found below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import winsound as snd

def sound_decorator(function):
    def wrapped_function(*args,**kwargs):
        print('I am here')
        snd.PlaySound('Sound.wav', snd.SND_FILENAME)
        return function(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped_function

@sound_decorator
def cmd():
    print('command')

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Play', command = cmd)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```